# dplyr - row_number in mutate in a for loop

Tags: r, dplyr, row-number, mutate

Good evening,

I am new in R so this might be an easy question.

I have a dataframe, df, similar to the following:

station  date   day1   day2   day3 . . . day365
a        0101   100     200     300 . . . 400
a        0201   100     200     300 . . . 400
a        0301   100     200     300 . . . 400
.         .      .       .       .  . . .  .
a        3112   100     200     300 . . . 400
b        0101   150     170     250 . . . 500
b        0201   150     170     250 . . . 500
b        0301   150     170     250 . . . 500
.         .      .       .       .  . . .  .
a        3112   150     170     250 . . . 500

In other words, each station is observed 365 days and there are 365 columns, one for each day where each column has duplicate values for each station.

I would like to create the variable "day" in the following way:

station   date    day
a         0101    100
a         0201    200
a         0301    300
b         0101    150
b         0201    170
b         0301    250

I tried using the following code in r:

```
for(i in 1:365) {
 colnum <- 2+i
 df <- df %>%
  group_by(station) %>%
  mutate(day = ifelse(row_number()==i, df[i, colnum], day))
}
```

This seems to work only for the first station but not for the following stations: would you know how to solve this?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Try with `df %>% tidyr::pivot_longer(-c(station, date), values_to = "day")` to reshape your data to the desired format.